# How to call sql table' info into asp.net?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to connect and load any fields of table into a web form.more explain is that ,I want a SQL server connection in a web form and choose a database and then load all of fields and data type into a table.
for example i've a table with below features :

```
field      type  
id          int  
name      nvarchar(50)  
email     nvarchar(50)
```

now i want to call them into web form not their values or records!
i hope explain it clearly
thanks for your solutions for help me...

Comment: Why all those different tags. Don't tag products not involved!

Comment: @jarlh, OK.I remove them

Comment: Just read some documentation. Perhaps this will help you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you can make a query for sys tables ... you can try something like this

```
select tab.name, col.name, typ.name, col.max_length, * from sys.columns col
join sys.tables tab on col.object_id = tab.object_id
join sys.types typ on col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
where tab.name = 'Test'
```

Just change name of table and give it a go, you can use result of that query in your form